# to populate data in to Map<Id,Map<Id, List<Contact>>>

Tags: apex, map

Can some one give an example of how to populate data in to:

```
Map<Id,Map<Id, List<Contact>>>
```

Comment: Kindly specify the entire requirement. Both the IDs belong to which object and how you want to Map the data

Answer (score 3):

You should always provide an attempted effort when seeking assistance.

The following code will give you some insight into how you can populate nested maps. Unsure as to which `SObject Ids` you want to use as the `keySet()` for both maps, I have simply used `Account`.

```
Map<Id, Map<Id, List<Contact>>> strangeMap = new Map<Id, Map<Id, List<Contact>>>();

for (Account acc : [select id, (select id from Contacts) from Account limit 1]) {
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> innerMap = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
    innerMap.put(acc.Id, acc.Contacts);
    strangeMap.put(acc.Id, innerMap);
}
System.debug(strangeMap);
```

A Limit has been applied to my SOQL for testing purposes. You will need to modify per your need.

Also, I wish to point out a scenario to be aware of. In the above `SOQL for loop`, a [relationship query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) is performed. These are quite handy, but when attempting to access the child records, beware of System limits such as

> QueryException such as "Aggregate query has too many rows for direct
>   assignment, use FOR loop"

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple. You first need to fill the internal Map and then using that Map you need to fill outer Map.

```
Map<Id,Map<Id, List<Contact>>> accconmap = new Map<Id,Map<Id, List<Contact>>>();
//Here accList is list of accounts records
for(Account acc : accList) {
   //if you want to append in existing map or there re chances that you will get same key multiple time then we use this.
   if(!accconmap.containsKey(acc.Id))
        accconmap.put(acc.Id, new Map<Id, List<Contact>>());

    //create internal map and fill it
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> conmap = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
    conmap .put(acc.Id, acc.contacts);
    accconmap.put(acc.Id, conmap );
    //you can also do this
    //accconmap.get(acc.Id).get(acc.Id).addAll( acc.contacts );
    // don't forget to add null check here

}
```